# Cloudinary video or image upload

Tags: node.js, api, postman, multer, cloudinary

Cloudinary is a cloud-based service that provides an end-to-end media management solution for images and videos. With Cloudinary, you can easily upload your images and videos to the cloud and then access them from anywhere, using a simple API.

what is Use the Cloudinary Management Console?

exaplain about Cloudinary  Management Console and sample code for node js?

Answer (score 1):

For more information in regards to the Cloudinary Media Library console (DAM) I would recommend checking out the following section of the Documentation - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/dam_digital_asset_management as well as - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/digital_asset_management_overview - from there, you can branch to specific topics for more detailed information and examples, such as in regards to uploading assets via the Media Library - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/dam_upload_store_assets.

In regards to Node JS, you'll want to start off with the quick start guide - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_quickstart - which will get you set up and using the API via the Node JS SDK in a matter of minutes. You'll be able to configure the SDK, upload your assets, transform them and get the details of your assets back. Once you've got that working you could find the full Node JS SDK documentation here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration.